# Spring ApplicationEventPublisherAware - Publisher not getting set

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Working with the ***Spring Tool Suite release 3.6.1*** to create a web page. The application receives outside events that it needs to propagate up to the UI.

Was pointed to/found information about **ApplicationEventPublisherAware** (relevant links http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/observer-pattern-with-spring-events.html and http://www.programmingforliving.com/2012/10/event-handling-in-spring.html.) Implemented as suggested but the **setApplicationEventPublisher**() method is not getting called so the publisher is not getting set.

The object has a default constructor which as I understand it is necessary for the bean to work correct. For testing purposes, it also has another public constructor that accepts parameters. The default constructor calls the other constructor to do its work. A snippet of my code is:

```
public class NodeObserver extends NodeObserverBase
implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware
{
  private ApplicationEventPublisher mPublisher;

  /** Default constructor using singleton items */
  public NodeObserver() {
    this(A.getInstance(), B.getInstance(), A.getInstance().getC());
  }
  public NodeObserver(final A a, final B b, final C c)
  {
    .....
  }
  .....
  public void setApplicationEventPublisher(
                final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher)
  {
    mPublisher = publisher;
  }
  .....
}
```

Any ideas why the set publisher method is not getting called? The links talk about changing the bean properties, but I can not find any file with the beans XML.

What am I doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Lori <*>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer through various investigation.

I turned my class into a controller. That is I added the @Controller directive to just before the class line:

```
@Controller
public class NodeObserver extends NodeObserverBase
implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware
{
  .....
}
```

Spring Tools took care of the rest.

Cheers
Lori <*>

Comment: `@Component` would have been enough.